# How to create an ArrayList of books that filters out books above a maxPages value?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having trouble understanding arrays/arrayList so I would really appreciate your help!

Question:
You’ve been given a list of books to read over the summer, but you need to trim down the list of books so you can finish all of them.

That takes a List of Books as a parameter, removes all Books from the `readingList` that have more than `maxPages` pages, then returns the resulting list.

You can access the number of pages of a Book by calling book.getNumPages(). The Book class is provided for reference.

Here is what I have:

```
public List<Book> filterBooks(List<Book> readingList, int maxPages) {
    List<Book> resultList= new ArrayList<Book>();  
    for(int i=0; i<readingList.size(); i++) {
        if (book.getNumPages() <= maxPages) {
            resultList.add(readingList.get(i));
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: You have merely forgotten to retrieve the book from the current index in the loop of readingList. Marking for closure as this is unlikely to help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the book from the list in your code by changing

```
book.getNumPages()
```

to

```
readingList.get(i).getNumPages()
```

---

You can do it in much cleaner way as :

```
public List<Book> filterBooks(List<Book> readingList, int maxPages) {
    return IntStream.range(0, readingList.size())
            .filter(i -> readingList.get(i).getNumPages() <= maxPages)
            .mapToObj(readingList::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

or simply

```
public List<Book> filterBooks(List<Book> readingList, int maxPages) {
    return readingList.stream()
            .filter(i -> i.getNumPages() <= maxPages)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```